# Obtaining printed copies of the textbook series Unified Modern Mathematics

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy

I'm seeking the textbooks that were released in the 1960's call Unified Modern Mathematics. I'm aware 3 parts of the course exist online but I would like to use them in hard copy form. I find these books highly intuitive if used right. Also, Archive.org has [some courses](https://archive.org/details/unifiedmodernmat00seco) but not all 6. Wikipedia mentions that the publisher Addison Wesley released hard copies. If anyone has any information on how to obtain these books, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to buy copies, or do you just want to check them out of a library?

Answer (score 3):

In order to help you, we should know which country you are from. In Germany, the library of the MPI in Berlin seems to be the only library where you can find these books, see http://gso.gbv.de/DB=2.1/

Answer (score 2):

I studied in one of these programs from 1971-1975.  This program taught me how to think.  Some of the books can be found here: https://eric.ed.gov/?q=Unified+Modern+Mathematics

Answer (score 1):

Teacher College should have full sets of Unified Modern Mathematics, 1-6 course.

From the first pages of the textbook (FYI - Columbia is in New York City, US)-

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please expand on this a bit... what is UMM?  Google is not helping me much...

Comment: @XanderHenderson Given the context, presumably "UMM" is "Unified modern mathematics" that the question is asking for. However, I have no idea is "Teacher college" and whether it is specific to a country, city, university, etc.

Comment: I did an internet search for "Teacher College" and couldn't identify it.  What country or state is it in?

Comment: Folks, this is a new user making a genuine attempt to be helpful, so the two downvotes seem out of line to me. It was very common in the US about 100 years ago for there to be colleges called "teachers' colleges." I think some of them got their names and missions upgraded to plain old "college" or "university," while i this particular case it seems clear that it was a college falling under the organizational umbrella of Columbia. So the teachers' college at Columbia probably no longer exists, but the books may still be sitting on a shelf in the same library.

Comment: @BenCrowell - Indeed, I edited to help OP, and to be welcoming to a new member.

Comment: @BenCrowell et al: Teachers College, Columbia University exists! [I got my Ph.D. from TC CU in 2014...] I checked their library - I have access as a graduate - and, indeed, they have UMM books. Here is a link to the library: https://library.tc.columbia.edu/